# Windows Server 2016 binds to ipv4, but not to ipv6

Tags: ipv6

I'm running Windows Server 2016 on an Intel S1200SPLR board. I try to run it with IPV6, but so far, it does not bind to any adapter, only ipv4 works. I only got a virtual DC to keep its DNS server address.